# formatting axis labels based on axis label values

Tags: vb.net, mschart

I have a P/L chart which has a left scale (Y axis) which starts from a negative value. I want to format the axis labels (the major tick mark labels) so that the negative ones are red.
Something like;

```
If cht.ChartAreas(chtarea).AxisX.MajorTickMark.Value < 0 Then
        cht.ChartAreas(chtarea).AxisY.LabelStyle.Font = New Font("Verdana", 9.0F, FontStyle.Bold, Color.Red)
    Else
        cht.ChartAreas(chtarea).AxisY.LabelStyle.Font = New Font("Verdana", 9.0F, FontStyle.Bold, Color.Black)
    End If
```

Of course that doesn't work since MajorTickMark doesn't have a value property. How does one make this work? I've done it in VBA, but that's not helping me here.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how you can change color several labels, but you can add your own `CustomLabels` in appropriate position from code:

```
cht.ChartAreas(chtarea).AxisY.CustomLabels.Add(new CustomLabel(..., Color.Red));
```